# Is it safe to simply change web page doctype HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.0 to doctype HTML5?

Tags: html, doctype

Suppose I want to change a legacy web site to be "HTML5"-ish. Is it safe to simply change the heading `doctype` as below?

```
<!doctype html>
```

The original doctype might be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

If changing to `<!doctype html>` has no possibility of ruining how the legacy web page is rendered, I would assume it is safe.

Answer (score 5):

Why yes, yes it is.

As a matter of fact, HTML5 was designed specifically for this, so that anyone could simply change their doctype without touching the markup and it would be valid.

Comment: Exactly what i was going to say. +1

Comment: On the contrary, is it possible to ruin the page if change a <!doctype html> page to be xhtml-doctype? Is it possible a "<br>" instead of "<br/>" break the rendering?

Comment: you have a good rep so maybe I don't understand.  the header can be changed and content can be displayed but that can't assure strict markup though in the actual content?  Maybe I am missing something, perhaps you can expand.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant HTML5 is looser then the 4.01 strict, so it would still validate.

Comment: @MorganCheng No, that's because browser try very hard to work with invalid HTML, though it does so very successfully usually (that's what makes it a good browser!), `<br>` vs `<br />` won't break the layout, you need to try very hard to do that, and it has nothing to do with the doctype you declare.

Comment: +1 thanks Truth, that's great information and much appreciated :)  Maybe you could update yur answer with a bit more of this info :)

Comment: Not true. Look at answer below. Changing this in my app definitely breaks line-heights.

Answer (score 5):

Almost safe.

This doctype:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

causes limited-quirks/almost standards mode in browsers, while this doctype:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

and this doctype

`<!doctype html>`

cause standards mode in browsers.

The difference being in the way some inline elements are vertically aligned in line boxes.

Answer (score 2):

If your "loose" document includes deprecated tags such as "font" or "frameset" then the page will not validate once you change it to HTML5. Will it work? Yes, most likely. Will it be valid? Depends on the actual content. Most likely your strict documents, if they were valid will still be valid, but the "loose" ones might not be.

As to what will happen to the display? That depends. I have found changing a transitional document to HTML5 results in display changes in some browsers -- in some case radical enough that I had to change them back until I had time to rewrite the pages in question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of safe.

It will reliably trigger the same rendering modes across browsers, so you will not get any differences that will effect end users.

It will also change the rules that a validator will use to check the document, so it might introduce problems for your QA process as documents need to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out the hard way that it's NOT safe. I needed some HTML5 elements in an old website, working for a few years now. I needed to change the doctype to html because some browsers wouldn't work with the new elements otherwise.

It turned out that in javascript the `domobject.name` doesn't work with the new `doctype`. You have to use `domobject.attributes["name"].value`. Long story short this simple thing created major problems with the website's core functionality.

Thus, it's best to test everything after changing the `doctype` because it can break various things of which you wouldn't think...